# searching case-sensitive in txt-files

Tags: php, search, full-text-search, case-sensitive, lowercase

I have a php-script to search in my webspace-files. I can toggle (case) if I want to search case-sensitive.
It function if I toggle case-sensitive. But when deselect this option I get no result if my word is in upper-case. So I think that the script lowers every time. But I can't find, even now after hours, what is wrong...

PHP 8.3

[search_all.php on my webspace](https://gallery.b22.de/search_all.php)

The script gives me results. So if you try on the website linked above with the german Geist (=ghost) it gives me **with toggled on "case-sensitive" 138 hits**. **But**  **with toggled off it gives me "Sorry No Result Found."** even so the result must have been 159. So I think there must be a fault with the strtolower-command?

Any idea?

If I insert the whole script, I don`t get an error in the php-sandbox on [PHP Sandbox][1] here`s the the part of script which handles "case":

```
<?php
$count = 0;

function getDirContents($dir, &$results = array()) {
    global $count;
    $searchStrings = array();

    if(isset($_POST['searchStrings'])) 
        $searchStrings = json_decode($_POST['searchStrings'], true);
    
    if ($_POST['search'] == null) { echo "1"; exit;}
    
    ini_set('max_execution_time', $_POST['maxtime']);
    
    $_SESSION['searchString'] = $_POST['search'];
    
    echo "<script>var elm = document.getElementById('search');elm.value='$_POST[search]';</script>";
    
    if (!isset($_POST['case']))
        $string = strtolower($_POST['search'] ?? '');
    else 
        $string = $_POST['search'];
    
    $files = scandir($dir);
    
    foreach ($files as $key => $value) {
        $path = realpath($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value);
        if (!is_dir($path)) {
            if (!isset($_POST['case'])) 
                $content = strtolower(file_get_contents($path));
            else 
                $content = file_get_contents($path);

            $label = null;
            $fileName = basename($path, '?' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
            $type = null;
            $types = array();...
```

So it must be an error, that the PHP-Sandbox can`t find...

Comment: Good code indentation and layout ___is for life, not just for Christmas___ and would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will be glad you took the time in the end.

Comment: Add [error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/) to the
top of your file(s) _while testing_ right after your opening PHP tag for example. 
Even if you are developing on a server configured as LIVE you will now see any errors. 
`<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: The solution was:

Answer (score 0):

When you want to compare to strings in a case-insensitive way you have to convert both strings to lower (or upper).

```
if(strtolower($str_a) == strtolower($str_b)){
    // match
}
```

As your code is incomplete and in the shown part only one of strings is converted to lower case, I think you have forgot to convert the other string to lower.

Comment: But aren`t both inverted with:
if (!isset($_POST['case']))
        $string = strtolower($_POST['search'] ?? '');
and
if (!isset($_POST['case'])) 
                $content = strtolower(file_get_contents($path));

Answer (score 0):

For simple search maybe you can do something like this

```php
$stringInWhichSearching = "Hello world, Geist is here.";
$search = "geist";
$caseSensitiveSearch = false;

if($caseSensitiveSearch === true) {
    // strpos is case sensitive
    $foundAtIndex = strpos($stringInWhichSearching, $search);
}
else {
    // stripos is case insensitive
    $foundAtIndex = stripos($stringInWhichSearching, $search);
}
if($foundAtIndex !== false) {
    echo "found at index $foundAtIndex" . PHP_EOL;
}
else {
    echo "not found" . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Solution with count handling

```php
$stringInWhichSearching = "Hello world, Geist is here.";
$search = "geist";
$caseSensitiveSearch = false;
$pattern = preg_quote($search, '/');

if($caseSensitiveSearch === true) {
    // the option 'u' is for unicode
    $count = preg_match_all("/$pattern/u", $stringInWhichSearching, $matches);
}
else {
    // the option 'u' is for unicode, "i" is for case insensitive
    $count = preg_match_all("/$pattern/ui", $stringInWhichSearching, $matches);
}
echo "Founded $count times" . PHP_EOL;
```

Warning

Here is an XSS security issue

```js
echo "<script>var elm = document.getElementById('search');elm.value='$_POST[search]';</script>";
```

if `$_POST[search]` contains javascript, it is possible to do bad things

Comment: thank You for this hint with xss! 
There is an function in the script, I hope it is meant to prevent this:
function sanitize($text) {
    $temp = $text;
    $text = sanitize_core($text);
    $text = $text . " ";
    $text = str_replace('&amp;', '&', $text);
    $search = "/((?#Email)(?:\S+\@)?(?#Protocol)(?:(?:ht|f)tp(?:s?)\:\/\/|~\/|\/)?(?#Username:Password)(?:\w+:\w+@)?(?#Subdomains)(?:(?:[-\w]+\.)+(?#TopLevel Domains)
more in the next comment

Comment: (?:com|org|net|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|jobs|museum|travel|a[cdefgilmnoqrstuwz]|b[abdefghijmnorstvwyz]|c[acdfghiklmnoruvxyz]|d[ejkmnoz]|e[ceghrst]|f[ijkmnor]|g[abdefghilmnpqrstuwy]|h[kmnrtu]|i[delmnoqrst]|j[emop]|k[eghimnprwyz]|l[abcikrstuvy]|m[acdghklmnopqrstuvwxyz]|n[acefgilopruz]|om|p[aefghklmnrstwy]|qa|r[eouw]|s[abcdeghijklmnortuvyz]|t[cdfghjkmnoprtvwz]|u[augkmsyz]|v[aceginu]|w[fs]|y[etu]|z[amw]|aero|arpa|biz|com|coop|edu|info|int|gov|mil|museum|name|net|org|pro))(?#Port)

Comment: (?::[\d]{1,5})?(?#Directories)(?:(?:(?:\/(?:[-\w~!$+|.,=]|%[a-f\d]{2})+)+|\/)+|#)?(?#Query)(?:(?:\?(?:[-\w~!$+|\/.,*:]|%[a-f\d{2}])+=?(?:[-\w~!$+|.,*:=]|%[a-f\d]{2})*)(?:&(?:[-\w~!$+|.,*:]|%[a-f\d{2}])+=?(?:[-\w~!$+|.,*:=]|%[a-f\d]{2})*)*)*(?#Anchor)(?:#(?:[-\w~!$+|\/.,*:=]|%[a-f\d]{2})*)?)([^[:alpha:]]|\?)/i";
    return trim($text);

Comment: is this enough, or dosn`t it help with the javascript?

Comment: just using htmlentities and strip_tags should work fine (simple solution; quotes are not handled)

// remove html tags (just keep text)
$safeValue = strip_tags ($_POST[search]);

// transform characters into their html representation
$safeValue = htmlentities($safeValue)

echo "<script>var elm = document.getElementById('search');elm.value='$safeValue';</script>";

Comment: So the script is only to search strings in text files. Is there any need to prevent XSS issues?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was:

```
if (!isset($_POST['case'])) {
    $string = strtolower($_POST['search'] ?? '');
}else {
    $string = $_POST['search'] ?? '';
}
```

was on the wrong position it should be  under foreach ,
and instead of $string I used now $tmp

```
$files = scandir($dir);

foreach ($files as $key => $value) {
    $path = realpath($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value);
    if (!is_dir($path)) {
        if (!isset($_POST['case'])) {
            $content = strtolower(file_get_contents($path));
        }else {
            $content = file_get_contents($path);
        }
        $label = null;
        $fileName = basename($path, '?' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
        $type = null;
        $types = array();
    
        foreach ($searchStrings as $tmp) {
        
            if (!isset($_POST['case'])) {
                $tmp = strtolower($_POST['search'] ?? '');
            }else {
                $tmp = $_POST['search'] ?? '';
            }
```